# Cannot instantiate service client

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

I have a wpf C# application that calls a web service AddressValidationService. I know it used to work (before I started working on the project), but now it doesn't. The exception happens here:

```
var addrSvc = new AddressValidationServiceReference.AddressValidationServiceClient();
```

The exception is:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'AddressValidationServiceReference.IAddressValidationService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

This is from my app.config:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://rdbval/EASTServices/AddressValidationService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPolicyRetriever"
            contract="AddressValidationServiceReference.IPolicyRetriever"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IPolicyRetriever" />
        <endpoint address="http://rdbval/EASTServices/AddressValidationService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressValidationService"
            contract="AddressValidationServiceReference.IAddressValidationService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressValidationService" />
    </client>
```

Maybe somebody could tell what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain, but isn't the web.config (not app.config) used for this?

Comment: But my client application is not a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably stupid guess, but anyway: are you sure your config file is the one from your client application? =). try reading some AppSetting from it for example to ensure you are using the correct one if you are not sure. 
The config itself looks fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But yes, it is the app.config from my project. Maybe I should put it to the main application project? (The solution has multiple projects)

Comment: Sure! You should place this in the host process project (of client application)

Comment: Yes! It worked, so your guess was exactly right. Thanks. Спасибо, Алекс!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to Insert or Update the `endpoints` in your `.config` in the `ServiceModel client` project for `IAddressValidationService`